# Convert date April/2019 to 04/2019

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Now I'm having a date like this, `April/2019`. I wanted to convert it into `04/2019` in php. How to resolve this?

```
date('m/Y', strtotime($_POST`['card_form_plan_start_date']))
```

> What I Wanted - 04/2019 
>   Actual Result - 01/1970

Comment: Can you please check the `$_POST['card_form_plan_start_date']` value..

Comment: $_POST['card_form_plan_start_date'] value is April/2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) won't recognise `April/2019` as a date. Instead, you can use [`date_create_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) with the `F/Y` format, then reformat the output as `m/Y`:

```
echo date_create_from_format('F/Y', 'April/2019')->format('m/Y');
```

Output

```
04/2019
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Lh8vk)

Comment: Working Properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `/` with `-`

```
 date('m/Y', strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$_POST`['card_form_plan_start_date'])))
```

Comment: This works well too.